# Hyperledger Fabric v1 Network Configuration On Physical

Tags: configuration, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to deploy hyperledger fabric network on two physical machines. 
I've deployed it on single machine using this [Guide](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#create-join-channel). 
But it is not clear to me what should i change in configuration files to deploy it on different nodes.
What does host field in `configtx.yaml` mean? (for example `- Host: peer0.org1.example.com`) Is it name only of virtual host, or i should replace it with real ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider using follow [script](https://github.com/yacovm/fabricDeployment) to roll over the Fabric network on bare metal machines. In fact you can also use it to learn how to setup your network and what parameters and configuration you need to take care about.

**UPDATE**

The `Host` value of the `configtx.yaml` file is the endpoint of anchor peers for different organization. Where the key role of the anchor peers is to get two organization which participating on one channel get connected together, basically anchor peers used as a advertisement billboard allowing organization to share theirs membership in scope of particular channel.

While you going to deploy your network on bare metals you have to use real host names or IP addresses and make sure they are accessible. Basically this is not that different compared to the docker-compose configuration available in fabric-samples.

Comment: But what exactly should i change to set up network on TWO machines to interact with each other?

Comment: Well, you do not need to make machines to directly interact with each other, unless they are part of same organization, then you need to setup one to be a bootstrap peer for gossip protocol. If you will take a look on the script it has all the details on how one could setup Fabric network on bare metals.

Answer (score 0):

The name in the configtx.yaml, are the domains that will have your nodes (peer, orderer, CA), those will be hosted in your docker containers with those domains, they will comunicate using those.

You can replace them for your IP Addresses if it's easier to understand, but I recommend to leave them like that.

Also if you are preparing a multihost solution you will need to add an extra-host section to your docker-compose files.

```
extra_hosts:
- "peer1.org1.example.com:<Second machine IP address>"
```

Don't know if you could accomplish to start your hyperledger fabric but, I figured out how to setup a multihost Hyperledger Fabric not using Docker Swarm, and using the basic-network example included in the Hyperledger Fabric examples.

You can review it here, hope it helps you.

https://medium.com/1950labs/setup-hyperledger-fabric-in-multiple-physical-machines-d8f3710ed9b4